Verify and if not create the collection in firebase?
In Firebase before inserting the document first we need to check the data, if collection is not there we need to create the collection and insert the document. is it possible to do this or can we create the empty collections by default(I know it cant, but still asking)

If you create a document in a collection that does not yet exist, it is created when you create that document. When you query a collection that does not exist, the list of documents you get back will be empty. When you say that you want to "insert a document", can you elaborate with an example? Additionally, you have not specified which language you are targeting, what you have tried, and what is not working as expected.

It's not possible to create an empty collection. As the prior comment said, you can just create the new document in the named collection, and it will be immediate available for use.  Similarly, there is no need to ever delete an empty collection, as it will be "gone" after the last document is deleted.  Collections aren't at all like directories in a filesystem.  They are just a named group of documents that share indexes for queries.

there is fruits data and I am trying to add the data in the collection which is not exist in the database like..  db.adddocument("fruits",data);.. I don't have any fruits collection.. will this call create the table or do I need do any changes in call?

As Sam and Doug commented: a collection in Firestore is automatically created when a first document is added to it, and automatically removed when the last document is removed from it. There is no way to explicitly create collections, nor any way to have an empty collection.
If I want to make sure a collection exists, I typically create an easily identifiable document in it such as _README.
If I want to know whether the collection already exists, I either load that easily identifiable document, or run a get with a limit(1) against it.
